# Overflow-y not scrolling with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm making a chat and messages won't scroll.
The messages go to "insere-msg" and use the class .msg-prop, they're stored in Firestore and I use document.getElementById("insere-msg").innerHTML += message to add them.

HTML

```
<div id="corpo-msgs">
    <div id="insere-msg">
      <a class="msg-prop">Text</a>
      <a class="msg-prop">Text</a>
      <a class="msg-prop">Text</a>
      <a class="msg-prop">Text</a>
      <a class="msg-prop">Text</a>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-msg">
      <input id="input-msg" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" aria-label="Digite sua mensagem">
      <button id="envia-msg" class="btn btn-outline-light">Enviar</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#corpo-msgs{
width: 95%;
height: 81vh;
background-color: var(--fundo-secundario);
border-radius: 5px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
min-height: 0;
}
.footer-msg{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#insere-msg{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;


  }

.msg-prop{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F2AE30;
    margin-left: 20%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Made it in codepen, don't know if it helps
https://codepen.io/heitor-de-paula-ramos/pen/WNrqoLg

Answer (score 0):

```
#corpo-msgs{
overflow: hidden;
> #insere-msg{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

this will add a scroll bar at right and if you want to remove that scroll bar and still want scroll you can also add a padding-right like this

```
#corpo-msgs{
overflow: hidden;
> #insere-msg{
overflow-y: scroll;
padding-right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: #insere-msg already had the overflow-y: scroll. I added overflow: hidden to corpo-msgs and nothing changed

Comment: overflow-y: scroll;
        scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;
            background: transparent; /* Chrome/Safari/Webkit */
        }
you can also try above css on this id-insere-msg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just gave up o flex and made insere-msg inline-blog with vertical-align: bottom and made the messages display: block and it all worked out.